# Subsequence $n_j$ where $\int_0^1 f_{n_j}g\,dx$ converges when $g$ real-valued bounded measurable function.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $f_n$ is a uniformly integrable sequence of functions defined on $[0, 1]$. How do I see that there is a subsequence $n_j$ where $\int_0^1 f_{n_j}g\,dx$ converges when $g$ is a real-valued bounded measurable function?

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to show the sequence of real numbers is bounded, i.e. 
\begin{align}
\left| \int^1_0 f_n g\ dx \right|\leq M<\infty.
\end{align}
Since $\{f_n\}$ is a uniformly integrable family of functions, then there exists a $\delta>0$ such that 
\begin{align}
\int_A |f_n|< 1
\end{align} 
whenever $m(A)< \delta$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. In particular, if we sub-divide the interval $[0, 1]$ into intervals with length less than $\delta$, i.e. $[0, 1] = \bigcup^N_{k=1} I_k$ where $m(I_k)<\delta$ 
\begin{align}
\int^1_0|f_n| \leq  \sum^N_{k=1}\int_{I_k} |f_n| <N 
\end{align}
for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Finally, using the fact that $g \in L^\infty[0, 1]$, we get
\begin{align}
\left|\int^1_0 f_n g\ dx \right| \leq ||g||_\infty \int^1_0 |f_n|\ dx < ||g||_\infty N
\end{align}
for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: My interpretation is that the subsequence should be independent of $g.$

Comment: @zhw I thought since $L^\infty[0, 1]= (L^1[0, 1])^\ast$, then to say there exists one subsequence $f_{n_k}$ such that $g(f_{n_k})$ converges for all continuous linear functional $g$ seems very strange.

Comment: @zhw I could be very wrong.